# Where does "method" as a special term in OOP originate?

Tags: terminology, history, methods

"Method" is a special term in Object-Oriented Programming. Does anyone know when the word began to be used in this particular sense, and in connection with what programming language or other branch of quantitative learning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java and C# got *method* from C++, which got it from [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula).

And [Algol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL) probably had [influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#History) on Simula:

> Also, an MIT ALGOL version, AED-0, linked data structures ("plexes", in that dialect) directly with procedures, prefiguring what were later termed "messages", "methods" and "member functions"

Comment: IIRC, C++ usually prefers 'member function' over 'method'.

Comment: According to that same Wikipedia article, that places the coinage of the term (related to OOP) within the first half of the 60s.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to find a definite answer out there but the first language to refer to things as methods appears to have been Simula though this may well be false or retroactive. Given that functions (from math) and procedures (also from math) show up in programming languages, the best I can figure is that "Method" is short form for "Methodology".

All of these are Subroutines, bits of code making up a computer program. I'd imagine "Method" was chosen because the idea behind OOP style programming is to reuse code as much as possible. Thus, you could have a procedure but a method makes it more clear that it's a new style at work. Honestly, I've been known to call methods functions and I've heard functions called methods.

Comment: I'm afraid you 'figure' incorrectly - *method* (a process to achieve a goal) and *methodology* (the study) are have different meanings.

Comment: Also, "method" has existed as an English word for a very long time. There's no need to look for a longer word to contract from.

Comment: On using "function" instead of "method", that's largely the fault of C++, and due to the fact that C has no concept of a "procedure", only a "function" that returns `void`. C++ member functions are very closely related to ordinary functions (unlike in Simula) - having an implicit `this` parameter and (possibly) a runtime dispatch mechanism doesn't really change what you're dealing with. I don't know if C was first to treat functions and procedures as the same thing, but Pascal (a newer language) has `function` and `procedure` keywords - though IIRC, Pascal functions could have side-effects.

Comment: Specifically, *method* is a way to achieve a goal, a description/knowledge, not the process itself. This has a significance in connection with "class", another abstract concept, defining a type of objects. You get a class of objects and a method of doing X with each/any of the objects, as long as they are of that class. You apply a generic method to specific object and get results specific to that object.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for information on this for decades.  My guess so far is that the term came into Simula from the special subfield of numerical computation, where the specific algorithm to implement a function (e.g., an eigenvalue or whatever) is often called a *method*. This is because you may have various different numerical *methods* for computing the same mathematical function, with various tradeoffs.  In OOP, because of method overriding, you may have the "same" function implemented differently as appropriate for the class--e.g., *area* would be implemented differently for *Circle* and *Rectangle*, which are both *Shapes*, which have an *area*.  This seems a reasonable extension of the traditional concept of numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about etymology of this word in OOP history. But I know that it's not [deductional](http://www.thoughtresults.com/deductional-language) (deducable). A better term (a More Deductional Term or MDT) for it could be **reaction** or **act**

Comment: I am entirely sure that I do not agree with you. "Method" is a perfectly cromulent word for what the whole thing started out as, a way of modeling various things, with each 'thing' being of a class, having methods to change how the thing was. In the same way that methods change things in the real world, like.

Comment: I'd guess "method" originally described the implementation code, similar to "procedure" - the method/procedure/algorithm for computing the result. Using it for an interface where the implementation isn't known is a tad wierd, but originally (in Simula) "message" was probably used for that. Even so, when you call a method, you are invoking implementation code, even if you can't know (at the call site) which implementation.

Comment: I guess of the three words 'function', 'procedure', and 'method', 'function' has a mathematical connotation (map inputs to outputs), 'procedure' is imperative (perform a series of steps, also used in the same sense in the military); 'method' doesn't have either connotation, which is probably why it is preferred in OOP.

Comment: @Vatine +1 for "cromulent"

Answer (score -1):

Programmers with REAL BASIC, VBx and VB.net background are aware of two types of method declarations "FUNCTION" & "SUB". BASIC family of languages allow to declare a function with the "FUNCTION" keyword as well as the "SUB" keyword.
The difference between these two is that a "FUNCTION" can or will not return a value where as a "SUB", just executes the code but will not return any value.
But with the advent of OO concepts, terms sub and function are started being used interchangeably as methods.

Comment: Same goes for Pascal's procedure/function

Comment: VB uses "Function" and "Sub", short for "Subroutine", not "Method".

Comment: I doubt Alan Kay was thinking Basic when coming up with OOP and Smalltalk